# JSON library for C# with System.XML namespace like scheme

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, xml, json.net

We are planning to move all our XML data handing to json handling. so that streamlined conversation between UI code and backend of the application. Is there any C# library which provides direct one to one class functionality mappings for System.XML namespace.

Comment: Json is not just another XML. Using the right tools json maps directly to code. That means there is no need to parse it like you would XML. xmlObject.SelectSingleNode("a/b/c") would just translate to jsonObject.a.b.c. In my opinion you are using json wrong, if you are just using it as a replacement for XML. But if you want the mappping library as a means to translate a large codebase to a temporary solution, I understand your needs. However, I don't know of any such library.